# Updating embedded precompiled .APK into Android ROM

Tags: android, google-play

I've built an Android Lock Screen application similar to [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.next).

Now, I want to create a custom Android ROM that will be using the lock screen as default, or at least make it preinstalled.

I've found a lot of tutorials on how do I pre-install a .apk into an custom Android ROM and this seems something I can do now.

But my question is: Will I be able to update the lock screen app via Google Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I be able to update the lock screen app via Google Play?

Yes, you can update ROM apps via Google Play without problems (assuming your app is not violating Google Play ToS but that's pretty obvious).